# New openvpn server clients can ping layer 2 but not layer 3 (DNS)

Tags: networking, server, dns, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to configure a new openvpn server and my clients can connect to the server, ping 4.2.2.2, but fails at layer 3 (DNS).

error:

```
ping google.com
temporary failure in name resolution
```

server config:

```
mode server
tls-server
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca      /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert    /etc/openvpn/server/issued/server.crt
key     /etc/openvpn/server/private/server.key
dh      /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem

server 10.9.8.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo         # Compression - must be turned on at both end
persist-key
persist-tun
#status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
verb 1  # verbose mode
user nobody
group nogroup
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
client-to-client
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "redirect-gateway bypass-dhcp"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 137.220.63.245"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 4.2.2.2"
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
```

iptables:

```
root@vultr:~# cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4 
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jun 16 04:19:35 2021
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2774:359035]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1375:169341]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1396:189514]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [629:154223]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2025:343737]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 16 04:19:35 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jun 16 04:19:35 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1375:169341]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1396:189514]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [629:154223]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 16 04:19:35 2021
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jun 16 04:19:35 2021
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [93:6515]
:INPUT ACCEPT [19:1048]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:76]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 16 04:19:35 2021
```

client config:

```
root@hvm-debian01:/etc/openvpn# cat /etc/openvpn/client.conf
client
remote 1.1.1.1
dev tun
nobind
tls-client
cert /etc/openvpn/client2.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client2.key
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
comp-lzo
verb 5
ping-restart 60
log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
```

How to I get openvpn to support dns for my clients?

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Doesn't help

Upon connecting, my

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

appears to update correctly.

```
root@hvm-debian01:/etc/openvpn# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 137.220.63.245
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the push DNS from 137.220.63.245 to 4.2.2.2 fixed the issue.

```
dig google.com. @137.220.63.245
```

from the client revealed the issue.